# How to improve fitness impact of jogging in place

Tags: jogging

As per answers to [Can run in place endlessly, but tire for distance. Why?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/36087/8039), jogging in place doesn't provide the same exercise as actual running. For various reasons, for the last several weeks, I've had to do more of my exercising in the house. I generally don't so much jog in place as travel at a walking pace with running cadence around the house (longer strides greatly increase the risk of running into furniture), but I know it's still not quite the same, and I think it's been contributing to my calves being tighter than they ought to be. Are there any good modifications I can make to improve the quality of this exercise until I can jog outside again?

Comment: Not even attempting to answer here, but can you not throw in some jump rope stuff (obviously if you have low ceilings, the answer is no).

Comment: I don't think jump rope will work in my environment. I may just have to keep reminding myself to high step.

Comment: Damn, sorry dude, only idea's I've really got are that or kettlebell swings

Comment: @SeanDuggan Quick feet is a good addition. Also, you can mix in drops (like burpees). It goes like this: Start running in spot - sprint speed - quick feet - drop - back up - quick feet - sprint speed - run - ...